# How is progress towards the Moments of Triumph trackers calculated?

Tags: destiny-2

I am interested to know if anyone has figured out how the trackers work for Moments of Triumph accomplishments?

Last night I got the last of the weapons from the Curse of Osiris wheel on Mercury and got Sagira's ghost shell and the accomplishment updated on the D2 app within a few minutes.

Then I grabbed 2 of the last 6 region chests I hadn't opened and again this updated on the D2 app in a couple of minutes.

Finally, I did two adventures that I needed to reach twenty unique adventures accomplishment but this didn't update and hasn't updated yet around 12 hours later.

I was playing with my second character, so it is likely that the other 18 adventures were completed with my main character, I am wondering if this specific stat is tracked by character rather than globally like the other two?

I will complete two unique adventures with my main character tonight and update but this seems odd that some would be tracked per character and others across all characters.

Assuming that this isn't a bug, is there a list of how each accomplishment is tracked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accomplishments shown are for the character that has the most of them.

All region chests (except for Mercury and Mars) are for your entire account: if you open it on one character, it's considered open for all characters. This is why getting the chests on your alt updated the count immediately.

For the Adventures in particular, the goal isn't to finish 20 Adventures, but 20 unique Adventures. Since your main character has 18 Adventures completed, even if the two done on your alt are new, if your alt has less than 18 Adventures completed it will still use your main character for the total.